# Which C++/Java graphics library does React Native use?

Tags: java, c++, react-native

Since Flutter is using *Skia* for graphics, I was wondering what the equivalent for that would be for React Native.

I managed to find an android.graphics.Canvas class in the React Native source code but that's about it. Finding it a bit harder to wrap my head around the React Native engine as opposed to the Flutter engine.

Comment: What if it uses a library from COBOL?

Comment: @user4581301 Whichever language it may be. I just assumed it would be either C++ or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to Flutter, React Native doesn't render native UI elements on its own.

`View` and `Text`, which are building blocks for React Native UI alter the corresponding OS  UI elements, and rendering is handled by Native code via [React Native Bridge](https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-ios).

This architecture makes React Native not suitable for graphic-intensive apps like drawing or games.

Sponsored by Shopify, William Candillon and Christian Falch are bringing Skia to React Native - https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/